# Google maps javascript DirectionRenderers limit

Tags: javascript, google-maps, directions

I am looking to display many routes on one instance of map, each route with different color. For it I created an array of DirectionsRenderer objects and assigning separate DirectionsRenderer for each route. 
The problem is GoogleMap component displays only first 10 DirectionsRenderer, I was not able to find any info on this limitation in google developers website. Is there any way to use more than 10 DirectionsRenderers at same time?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with the DirectionsRenderer.  You are receiving a status of `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` from the DirectionsService.

Comment: Why is it happening? I am sending 11 different requests. Not many qaypoints in one request. I'm also using api key.

Comment: There is a quota and a rate limit on all google's services, you are probably hitting the rate limit.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what @geocodezip said:

**"I was not able to find any info on this limitation in google developers website."**

Here you go:

> [Usage limits and
> policies](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#quotas)
>
> -Up to 8 waypoints per request, plus the origin and destination. // 10 overall
>
> -50 requests per second, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.
>
> -2,500 free requests per day, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries; enable billing to access higher daily quotas,
> billed at $0.50 USD / 1000 additional requests, up to 100,000 requests
> daily.